# I want to create an object that slides along another

Tags: rigging, armature

I'm a bit new to Blender. Still learning new functions.

This truck will be transforming into a robot. The block you see in the red square needs to slide in between the two pieces of metal on either side (the track). It must simply go back, towards where the red arrow is pointing, and back to its original position.

I don't want this to happen simply with animation or physics. I want it to happen when I either grab and move it (it should not be able to move anywhere but the track I mentioned), or by using an armature I have yet to build (still staying within the track).

I just don't know how to ensure this block cannot move anywhere but back and forth between these two tracks, regardless of the what means I choose to pull or push it.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need an armature? The track seems to be straight, why not just move it in a straight line? What are you trying to do here?

Comment: He's going to transform from a cement truck to a robot. When he's a robot, he'll need to armature for posing. However, I found a way by creating some shape keys. I would still like to know how to do it though.

Comment: I would suggest editing the question and providing more context. Moving an object along a track is not a complicated issue, and there are many ways to do that, but you have not yet received a single answer. I suspect since you haven't provided much context people are probably hesitating to provide answers only to find out new information about what you are really attempting to do here and that you need a different solution. I think you are not getting answers, because the question is not clear enough.

Comment: I edited the question. Hopefully this clears what I'm asking up.

Comment: Still not clear at all to be honest. I gave it a shot with answer anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's a separate object(I have no idea how it's set up since you have not provided that info), you can simply apply object rotation(if needed) and lock location transform axis. Then you can parent it to some other object(the track maybe) so it moves with it, but when you attempt to move the object alone it will be constrained to move in local object space in the axis that is not locked.

[image]

You could also use limit constraint to limit the amount of movement. Note that it can be used in Local Space as well for this to work with it being parented to something else and moved around:

[image]